Open third party link in modal popup using headless drupal 10
Trying to open external link in modal popup itself. While implementing i found that internal pages are rendering properly but the ask is that external link should get open in popup using headless drupal 10.
Is there any method available in drupal 10 or how can we achieve it.
Below set of code used for opening modal
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:600}" data-dialog-type="modal" href = "https://www.google.com">External Website</a>

If we click on External Website link, google should get open in popup.

have a look here https://www.trycatchdebug.net/news/1311369/third-party-links-in-headless-drupal-modals
